# Python Tabulate

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I merge multiple tables in python using tabulate package?

`append` is not working when concatenating the two tables in python.The tables are implemented using tabulate package in python.

```
table_1 = [["Value_1",1,2],["Value_2",2,4],["Value_3",2,3]]
table_2 = [["Value_1",1,2],["Value_2",2,4],["Value_3",2,3]]
table_3 = table_1.append(table_2)
print table_3
```

Answer (score 3):

For " concatenating the two tables"  you probably want [list.extend](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), not append. Append will insert the second list as a single item to the first one. Also note that `extend` will modify the source list in-place and return `None`:

```
>>> table_1 = [["Value_1",1,2],["Value_2",2,4],["Value_3",2,3]]
>>> table_2 = [["Value_1",1,2],["Value_2",2,4],["Value_3",2,3]]
>>> table_3 = table_1.extend(table_2)
>>> print table_3
None
```

`table_3` is now `None`, while `table_1` was extended:

```
>>> print table_1
[['Value_1', 1, 2], ['Value_2', 2, 4], ['Value_3', 2, 3], ['Value_1', 1, 2], ['Value_2', 2, 4], ['Value_3', 2, 3]]
```

Comment: They could well be after `.extend`, but I think the "not working" bit is that `append` and indeed `extend` modify the source list in-place,  and return `None` so I'm guessing that's what the OP is having issues with... It might be worth addressing

Answer (score 1):

`list.append` or `extend` mutates the list inplace and returns `None`, so here your `table_3` gets `None` in it. You can use `+` to add concatenate two lists:

```
In [251]: table_1 = [["Value_1",1,2],["Value_2",2,4],["Value_3",2,3]]
     ...: table_2 = [["Value_1",1,2],["Value_2",2,4],["Value_3",2,3]]
     ...: table_3 = table_1 + table_2
     ...: print table_3
[['Value_1', 1, 2], ['Value_2', 2, 4], ['Value_3', 2, 3], ['Value_1', 1, 2], ['Value_2', 2, 4], ['Value_3', 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply append because the values will be in list format..........

> table_1 = [["Value_1",1,2],["Value_2",2,4],["Value_3",2,3]]
>      table_2 = [["Value_1",1,2],["Value_2",2,4],["Value_3",2,3]]
>      table_1.extend(table_2)
>      print table_1